# No tag "foreach" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, taglib

I'm developing an application (on Eclipse) with some jsp pages on Tomcat.

I've already downloaded the JSTL jars

```
(http://jstl.java.net/download.html)
```

and added them to web-inf/lib and to my build path.

However, when I access the page, I always get:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/AccessControl2] threw exception [/ADAccess.jsp (line: 16, column: 1) No tag "foreach" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ADAccess.jsp (line: 16, column: 1) No tag "foreach" defined in tag library imported with prefix "c"
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
```

As for my JSP, this is how I am doing it:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<HTML>
<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript" src="saveOptions.js"></script>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveADAccess.jsp">

<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="nbsi.config.access.ADGroupListBean" scope="page"/>

<select name="withoutAccess" size="5">

<c:foreach var="item" items="${obj.withoutAccess}">
    <option>${item}</option>
    </c:foreach>
</select>

<select name="withAccess" size="5">

</select>
<P>
        <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT> 
    <input type="button" onClick="removeOptions(withoutAccess,withAccess)"value="Give Access" />
        <input type="button" onClick="removeOptions(withAccess,withoutAccess)"value="Remove Access" />
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've already searched for this problem, but the solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: use `forEach`, not `foreach`

Comment: Nice catch, @GrzegorzGrzybek, you should probably add that as an answer

Comment: Wow!! too late! Someone did it!

Comment: That was rather proofreading than answering ;)

Comment: It was the correct solution. Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the tagname is case sensitive. Use `<c:forEach` instead `<c:foreach`.

Answer (score -1):

refer below link,
https://springbootmvc.blogspot.com/2020/06/jstl-core-tag.html

Make sure the header to be added correct one,
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>